# Find all $S\in\mathbb{P}Gl(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that $\{Re(z)>0\}\rightarrow\{Re(z)>0\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all $S\in\mathbb{P}Gl(2,\mathbb{C})$ such that $\{Re(z)>0\}\rightarrow\{Re(z)>0\}$.

So my thought is to let $z,z_2,z_3,z_4\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $Re(z),Re(z_2),Re(z_3),Re(z_4)>0$. Then $$\frac{z-z_3}{z-z_4}\cdot\frac{z_2-z_4}{z_2-z_3}$$ maps $z_2\mapsto 1$, $z_3\mapsto 0$ and $z_4\mapsto \infty$. The problem is $Re(z_3)\not>0$. So how can I find all such maps?